# Trying to execute the given command which is one of the steps to work with ESP8266 device on Kaa development platform, on Linux

Tags: linux, cmake, esp8266, toolchain, kaa

The code is :-

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../kaa/toolchains/esp8266.cmake -DKAA_PLATFORM=esp8266 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel -DWITH_EXTENSION_CONFIGURATION=1 -DWITH_EXTENSION_EVENT=1 -DWITH_EXTENSION_LOGGING=1 -DWITH_EXTENSION_NOTIFICATION=1 -DWITH_EXTENSION_USER=1 -DWITH_EXTENSION_PROFILE=1 -DWITH_ENCRYPTION=OFF -DKAA_MAX_LOG_LEVEL=3
```

The output error messages I am getting is :-

> -- Toolchain path: ESP8266_TOOLCHAIN_PATH-NOTFOUND CMake Deprecation Warning at
>   /usr/local/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeForceCompiler.cmake:69
>   (message): The CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER macro is deprecated. Instead
>   just set CMAKE_C_COMPILER and allow CMake to identify the compiler.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first): kaa/toolchains/esp8266.cmake:40
>   (cmake_force_c_compiler) build/CMakeFiles/3.10.1/CMakeSystem.cmake:6
>   (include) CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
>
> --Default SDK location will be used: /opt/Espressif/esp-rtos-sdk CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project): The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
>
> ESP8266_TOOLCHAIN_PATH-NOTFOUND/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc is not a full
>   path and was not found in the PATH.
>
> Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the
>   environment variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to
>   the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the
>   PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct the path of  **xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc**.

Go to the directory where you have installed the esp-rtos-sdk.

Then then in the CMakeLists.txt change the ***/opt/Espressif/esp-rtos-sdk*** to the Full path of **esp-rtos-sdk**.

example: let I installed esp-rtos-sdk in ***/home/vipul/Espressif/esp-rtos-sdk/***
so in CMakeLists.txt ***/opt/Espressif/*** I change it to **/home/vipul/*Espressif/***

Also do the same changes it in the ***/kaa/toolchains/esp8266.make***.